# skew-symmetric linear map

Tags: lie-algebras

We all know the definition in the following

**Definition**. Let $\frak{g}$ be a Lie algebra. A Lie bialgebra structure on $\frak{g}$ is a skew-symmetric linear map $\delta_{\frak{g}}: \frak{g}\rightarrow \frak{g}\otimes \frak{g},$ called the cocommutator, such that

1. $\delta_{\frak{g}}^{*}: \frak{g}^{*}\otimes
       \frak{g}^{*}\rightarrow \frak{g}^{*}$ is a Lie bracket on
   $\frak{g}^{*}$,
2. $\delta_{\frak{g}}$ is a $1$-cocycle of $\frak{g}$ with values
   in $\frak{g}\otimes \frak{g}.$

My question is that ``what is a skew-symmetric linear map'' in the definition?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bialgebra); $\delta^*$ is skew-symmetric, not $\delta$. See also the Definition in $1.3$ [here](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/cmat/kosmann/lnp2.pdf).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, dear professor D. Burde, it seems that this definition is also OK. It appears in Char and Pressley's book ``A guide to quantum group''

Comment: @DietrichBurde Unfortunately, the second link doesn't work.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Lol - no, I meant that the link didn't (and still doesn't) work on my phone. But now I see that the link does at least work at my computer. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1):

The definition you posted is also OK. First, we need a  flip map $$\tau:\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}, x \otimes y \mapsto y\otimes x, \forall x,y\in \mathfrak{g}.$$ Then the skew symmetry of $\delta_{\mathfrak{g}}$ is given by
$$\tau \delta_{\mathfrak{g}}(x)=-\delta_{\mathfrak{g}}(x), \forall x\in \mathfrak{g}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see now.